# Is there any train_test_split in pyspark or MLLib?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

Is there any pyspark / MLLib version for this classic sklearm classic train_test_split code below?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(featuresonly, 
                                                    target, 
                                                    test_size = 0.2, 
                                                    random_state = 123)

# Show the results of the split
print("Training set has {} samples.".format(X_train.shape[0]))
print("Testing set has {} samples.".format(X_test.shape[0]))
print("Training set has good {} samples.".format(len(y_train) -y_train.sum()))
print("Testing set has good {} samples.".format(len(y_test) -y_test.sum()))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RandomSplit - as mentioned above - is the way to go

```
train, test = final_data.randomSplit([0.7,0.3], seed=4000)
```

Then, you can counts your labels in the train set

```
dataset_size=float(train.select("label").count())

Positives=train.select("label").where('label == 1').count()

percentage_ones=(float(Positives)/float(dataset_size))*100

Negatives=float(dataset_size-Positives)

print('The number of ones are {}'.format(Positives))

print('Percentage of ones are {}'.format(percentage_ones))

print(' The number of zeroes are {}'.format(Negatives))
```

Comment: Unfortunately randomSplit() lacks so many features like stratify which was there in train_test_split(). This function can't be its true alternative. Any suggestions?

Comment: Stratified sampling in pyspark can be achieved by using **sampleBy**, lets say the column on which you want to stratify the sample is "colname" 

     `sampled = df.sampleBy("colname", fractions={4: 0.2, 6: 0.4, 8: 0.2}, seed=0)`

Comment: Great and I did a little search and found out that it is without replacement, so perfect I believe it very much solves the purpose. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sampleBy.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation it's called [RandomSplit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.randomSplit.html)

There are many examples [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html) to see how it's used